# Why does \parskip add space after section headings inconsistently?

Tags: spacing, parskip

There are already several questions dealing with the extra vertical space after section headings that result from setting `\parskip` to a non-zero value.

Here, I just want to understand *why* extra space is added before normal paragraphs but not before lists. (I think this is a legitimate question and not a duplicate.)

As it can be seen in the picture below, there is extra space when the section starts with some text:

[image: No parskip (left) vs parskip (right), paragraph]

Yet no extra space when the section starts with an itemize:

[image: No parskip (left) vs parskip (right), itemize]

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\parskip=\smallskipamount

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{compactlist}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[compactlist]{%
  label=\enskip\textbullet,
  partopsep=0pt,
  topsep=0pt,
  parsep=0pt,
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Parskip}
%% \blindtext
\begin{compactlist}
  \item \blindtext
\end{compactlist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution is simple: *never* set a nonzero parskip. `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last I figured out what is going on by looking at LaTeX's source code.

When a regular paragraph follows a section heading, the vertical space between the heading and the first line of the paragraph is `AFTERSKIP + \parskip`, where `AFTERSKIP` is a skip hard-coded in the document classes. It can be changed by re-defining the sectioning macros `\section`, `\subsection`, and so on.

However, when a list construct (including environments such as `center`, `flushleft`, `flushright`) is the first thing after a section heading, the vertical spacing is different. The sectioning commands add `AFTERSKIP` as usual, and then the first `\item` command in the list adds `\parskip - \parsep`, but it does so with `\addvspace`, which may have puzzling results.

For the actual space added by `\addvspace` also depends on the value of `\lastskip` (in this case `AFTERSKIP`). For instance, if `\parskip - \parsep` is less than or equal to `AFTERSKIP`, then `\addvspace` will add nothing. If `\parskip - \parsep` is greater than `AFTERSKIP`, then `\addvspace` will add the space, but it will remove `AFTERSKIP`! In conlusion, the vertical space that is inserted between a section heading and a list construct depends on these 3 parameters - `AFTERSKIP`, `\parskip` and `\parsep` - and the rules of `\addvspace` for adding vertical space.

Comment: The `!` above appears to indicate surprise, but the description you give is the intended behaviour: `\advspace` adds the _maximum_ value of the specified skip and the previous skip so that if two display constructs follow each other you do not get both the below-skip of the first and the above-skip of the second, you just get the maximum of those values.

Answer (score 12):

`\parskip` is a TeX primitive which gets set to various values in LaTeX constructs, so setting it directly at the start of the document has a defined effect but possibly not as expected. In particular LaTeX lists manipulate `\parskip` to control the spacing before the list and between items, in particular before a list it is reset to values depending on  `\partopsep` and `\topsep`.